# PSQL (How to?): Update if exists else insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

```
Table name = leadgen_click_report
-----------------------------------
Columns:
-----------------------------------
platform
mobile
created
token
ip
is_phone
browser
device
```

I have a table as shown above. What is the best way to solve the following problem?:

The DB table can have multiple entries with the same mobile value or multiple values with the same token value. But for each unique token value, there will always be only one mobile value.

For example:

```
Mobile     token
xyz        123
xyz        456
pqr        123
```

Now, I have to update the "created" column if the mobile number with the token I provide exists, else I have to add a new row in the DB with all the fields. What is the best way to do this?

I can only think of using multiple statements like 1. Check if a row exists with provided mobile and token - if yes: update "created" else: insert new row

Comment: I think this is the best way u can do.

Comment: MERGE statement

Comment: @CaiusJard. Unfortunately Postgres does not support the Merge statement. The closest is "insert ... on confilct ... do update ..."

Comment: @belayer Hah, thanks.. when I read the question in its original form (before HWNN edited it) I read the "PSQL" in the title as "PLSQL"..

Answer (score 0):

Start with a unique index or constraint on `mobile`/`token`:

```
create unique index unq_leadgen_click_report_mobile_token on leadgen_click_report(mobile, token);
```

Then, you can use `on conflict`, which looks something like this:

```
insert into leadgen_click_report (platform, mobile, created, token, ip, is_phone, browser, device)
    values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    on conflict (mobile, token) do update created = excluded.created;
```